# Set up a SQL query with multiple AS

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called `visits`, which has columns `source`, `state`. `source` is `string` and `state` is `boolean`. I want to be able to group the `visits` based on *sources* and count for `false` states as well as `true` states.

Something like:

```
[
  {
    "source": "source_1",
    "count": 344,
    "false": 100,
    "true": 244
  },
  {
    "source": "source_2",
    "count": 340,
    "false": 123,
    "true": 217
  },
  {
    "source": "source_3",
    "count": 316,
    "false": 145,
    "true": 171
  }
]
```

So far I've done the query below which allows me to group them by `source`:

```
SELECT a.source, count  
FROM (
        SELECT 
            source, count(*)as count
        FROM visits
        GROUP BY source
      ) a
GROUP BY a.source, count
ORDER BY count DESC
```

How can I count the different states?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks the comment. I've fixed it now as I'm using `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT a.source, COUNT(*) as cnt,
       SUM( state ) as num_trues,
       SUM( NOT state) as num_falses  
FROM visits
GROUP BY a.source
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

In Postgres, you can phrase this as:

```
       SUM( state::INT ) as num_trues,
       SUM( (NOT state)::INT ) as num_falses
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @GrordonLinoff. Appreciate it :)